# How to reuse common parts of recursive union types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## TLDR

This works ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=17&pln=18&pc=33#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0HkAO05gD2UAPAKIB8yA3gFDIPIDkMwUAzmEwFzJkDc9Rk3YQEhEOh59BAX1qhIsRCgAKURbnxFSlGkIZMAbnAA2AVwjSBteYujwkyVYQDu0LVALFyVOo2YTCyteGwCmCAAPHGs5WlowAE88ZABlYABbHFMIMmioCHZ2YAlkAF5kEHMMgCNoZAAfZE4NEABzRrRMT29SdKycvJwCopKQKib1TTwvHRJ+7Nz8wuKJCkEE5JQ8yEkIdCGR1ZByyuq6qE6W0A6mjGwZ3vJI3fR9w5WxiedWsB65nYQPYHZajNadFzuKD-HyA4EfMHjDbiECcZqZRa8BaDUHHU7UZBBSy8AlEiC8ACsyFk1MEKLRUVe+1CLyBbxBw0+pQqpLMxJohL55OQFIANMgojheAB2am02hAA)):

```
type SimpleExpression = number | string | AddOperator<SimpleExpression> | PrintOperator<SimpleExpression>;
type ExtendedExpression = number | string | AddOperator<ExtendedExpression> | PrintOperator<ExtendedExpression> | PowerOperator<ExtendedExpression>;
```

But extracting common sub-type doesn't work ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0HkAO05gD2UAPAKIB8yA3gFDIPIDkMwUAzmEwFzJkDc9Rk3YQEhEOh59BAX1qhIsRCgAKURbnxFSlGkIZMAbnAA2AVwjSBteYujwkyVYQDu0LVALFyVOo2YTCyteGwCmCAAPHGs5WlowAE88ZABhQgBbDIkyaKgIdnZgCV9kAF5kEHMMgCNoZAAfZE4NEABzRrRMT29dKib1TTwvHV9BJJSAZWAMnFMIXJx8wuKQcrTM7JBF5aKS6dn5nYK9kApx5JRcyEkIdGOViXX0rJy8k9XySJv0O4fT-rONweYa9L4-P7vR5nQQBWjiECcZozOYQXgHVH-VbrajIIKWXi4-Fo5AAVmQsgpggRSKiEPQoW+EFu9yhpxxeLMBJonOCvFJABpkFEcLwAOwUqm0IA)):

```
type CommonExpression<E> = number | string | AddOperator<E> | PrintOperator<E>;
type SimpleExpression = CommonExpression<SimpleExpression>;
type ExtendedExpression = CommonExpression<ExtendedExpression> | PowerOperator<ExtendedExpression>;
```

Is there any way around it?

## Long description

Recently TypeScript (3.7) got extended support for recursive types, but still not everything is possible.
There are many questions on StackOverflow that explain recursive types, but there is one useful pattern that I can't find solution for.

A starting point is an Expression tree, where each operator has children that are Expressions. This works:

```
type Expression = number | string | AddOperator | PrintOperator;
interface AddOperator {
  'first': Expression;
  'second': Expression;
}
interface PrintOperator {
  'value': Expression;
}
```

Now we would like to make it more generic, so that we have SimpleExpression (with only `add` and `print`), and ExtendedExpression that also supports `power` operator.
We can do this, and it works ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=17&pln=18&pc=33#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0HkAO05gD2UAPAKIB8yA3gFDIPIDkMwUAzmEwFzJkDc9Rk3YQEhEOh59BAX1qhIsRCgAKURbnxFSlGkIZMAbnAA2AVwjSBteYujwkyVYQDu0LVALFyVOo2YTCyteGwCmCAAPHGs5WlowAE88ZABlYABbHFMIMmioCHZ2YAlkAF5kEHMMgCNoZAAfZE4NEABzRrRMT29SdKycvJwCopKQKib1TTwvHRJ+7Nz8wuKJCkEE5JQ8yEkIdCGR1ZByyuq6qE6W0A6mjGwZ3vJI3fR9w5WxiedWsB65nYQPYHZajNadFzuKD-HyA4EfMHjDbiECcZqZRa8BaDUHHU7UZBBSy8AlEiC8ACsyFk1MEKLRUVe+1CLyBbxBw0+pQqpLMxJohL55OQFIANMgojheAB2am02hAA)):

```
interface AddOperator<E> {
  'first': E;
  'second': E;
}
interface PrintOperator<E> {
  'value': E;
}
interface PowerOperator<E> {
  'value': E;
  'exp': E;
}

type SimpleExpression = number | string | AddOperator<SimpleExpression> | PrintOperator<SimpleExpression>;

type ExtendedExpression = number | string | AddOperator<ExtendedExpression> | PrintOperator<ExtendedExpression> | PowerOperator<ExtendedExpression>;
```

But now if we want to factor out the common part using a generic union type, we will fail ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0HkAO05gD2UAPAKIB8yA3gFDIPIDkMwUAzmEwFzJkDc9Rk3YQEhEOh59BAX1qhIsRCgAKURbnxFSlGkIZMAbnAA2AVwjSBteYujwkyVYQDu0LVALFyVOo2YTCyteGwCmCAAPHGs5WlowAE88ZABhQgBbDIkyaKgIdnZgCV9kAF5kEHMMgCNoZAAfZE4NEABzRrRMT29dKib1TTwvHV9BJJSAZWAMnFMIXJx8wuKQcrTM7JBF5aKS6dn5nYK9kApx5JRcyEkIdGOViXX0rJy8k9XySJv0O4fT-rONweYa9L4-P7vR5nQQBWjiECcZozOYQXgHVH-VbrajIIKWXi4-Fo5AAVmQsgpggRSKiEPQoW+EFu9yhpxxeLMBJonOCvFJABpkFEcLwAOwUqm0IA)):

```
type CommonExpression<E> = number | string | AddOperator<E> | PrintOperator<E>;
type SimpleExpression = CommonExpression<SimpleExpression>;
type ExtendedExpression = CommonExpression<ExtendedExpression> | PowerOperator<ExtendedExpression>;
```

The errors are:

```
Error: Type alias 'SimpleExpression' circularly references itself.
Error: Type alias 'ExtendedExpression' circularly references itself.
```

So the question is: Is there any way to define two different expression types, that share the common core?

> A bit of background about usage scenario: we want to provide
>   `SimpleExpression` in a library, but allow client code to define
>   additional operators, and register handlers for those. We'd like user
>   to be able to easily define his `ExtendedExpression` type, without too much typing.

Comment: Can you tell me why it is recursive, it looks strange that I have such thing like `value` and inside `{value}` which has `{value}` and so on what is a sense in such deep nesting possibility?

Comment: Expressions are recursive by nature: you can add results of addition `(a+b) + (c+d)`, and then add two things like that `( (a+b) + (c+d) ) + ( (e+f) + (g+h) )`, etc.  
Arbitrary nesting is required.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
type SimpleExpression = number | string | AddOperator<SimpleExpression> | PrintOperator<SimpleExpression>;
type ExtendedExpression = number | string | AddOperator<ExtendedExpression> | PrintOperator<ExtendedExpression> | PowerOperator<ExtendedExpression>;
```

there is at least one path where recursion should stop. For the case of `const simple: SimpleExpression = { value: { value: 5 } };`, which is of type `PrintOperator<PrintOperator<number>>`.

---

But if you use

```
type CommonExpression<E> = number | string | AddOperator<E> | PrintOperator<E>;
type SimpleExpression = CommonExpression<SimpleExpression>;
type ExtendedExpression = CommonExpression<ExtendedExpression> | PowerOperator<ExtendedExpression>;
```

recursion can never stop. In fact, the recursion occurs inherently in the type declaration itself. `SimpleExpression` will be of type `CommonExpression<SimpleExpression>`, but it will be extended to `CommonExpression<CommonExpression<SimpleExpression>>`, and then `CommonExpression<CommonExpression<CommonExpression<SimpleExpression>>>`, and so on, forming an endless recursion. That's why this type set-up is not accepted by TypeScript.

---

Interestingly, however,

```
type SimpleExpression = AddOperator<SimpleExpression> | PrintOperator<SimpleExpression>;
```

is still accepted, but no variables will satisfy this type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The recursion is not "infinite", because `CommonExpression` only **conditionally** expands to something dependent on it's argument. The recursion could therefore stop without issue. The fact that TypeScript's type analysis is written in such a way that it **considers it** infinitely recursive is not disputed here, but rather is a problem I'd like to work around.